# Or operator in assignment left side

Tags: php, logical-operators, or-operator

I've seen the next sentence in PHP code:

```
$a OR $a = $b;
```

What is the behavior of this code?

or

What is the purpose of this code?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi. Please tell - is `$a OR $a = $b` a part of SQL query?

Comment: I should think this is a syntax error in PHP - one equals sign is assignment, not comparison. We'd need to see more code, and some explanation/context would be good too.

Comment: This is a _conditional assignment_ statement. I expect it to leave the current value of _$a_ alone if it contains a 'true' value. Otherwise _$a_ gets set to the value in _$b_. Another way of saying it - set $a to the value of $b if $a is 'false'. The OR 'short-circuits' so if $a is 'true' evaluation stops. ;-/

Comment: The Ryan answer is the correct, I think.
Something like 'mysql_connect (...) or die (...)'.
However, I paste the code in context for evaluation:

 function get_theme_layouts($theme = NULL)
 {
  $theme OR $theme = $this->_theme;

  $layouts = array();

  foreach ($this->_theme_locations as $location)
  {
   // Get special web layouts
   if( is_dir($location.$theme.'/views/web/layouts/') )
   {
... (and so on) ...

Comment: Thank you all for your participation.

Comment: I apologize for the misuse of publishing tool. I am a novice at this.

Answer (score 1):

The operator "OR" is a Logical operator, used to check if one of two (or more) terms is true. if either $a or ($a = $b) is TRUE.
The operator "==" (in your question is =, but i think is == ) is a Comparison operator, used to check if $a is equal to $b (like same value, term A is true and term B is true, others cases).
Thanks

Comment: You might want to edit your answer, in line with Ryan's comment. The `=` in the original code is correct.

Comment: The symbol (=) in PHP is a basic assignment operator. Right?

Comment: You're correct. What the code is doing is checking to see if `$a` already has a value; if it has a value that evaluates to false, then it's assigning the value of `$b` to it. It works because the OR operation evaluates from left to right, and if the left hand side evaluates to true, then the right hand side is never checked. I've seen this construction in a couple of places, and while I like the compactness, I'd much rather have slightly more verbose code that's much easier to read when I come back to it six months later.